# Invalid Base64 string - DocuSign Create Envelope REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to send a PDF file using the `documentBase64` property. It is always giving me following error

> "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters".

I am using the ServiceNow application to send the attachment base64Encoded data to the docusign API.

Comment: Could you please give your request message in JSON format for example ? That would help to troubleshoot your issue

Comment: Your question currently can't be answered because you're not giving us sufficient information. Please detail exactly how you are telling ServiceNow to send an Envelopes: create request to DocuSign. The problem is that you're not telling ServiceNow to base64 encode the file. What type of file are you sending? PDF or something else? 

Help us help you...

Answer (score 0):

You need to `base64` encode the document bytes and add those encoded bytes to your request instead of the raw PDF bytes.